# Question about Modified Miller-Rabin Test

Tags: cryptography, primes

A few months ago I decided to write my own custom prime number generator. One of the tests I use is a modified Miller-Rabin test that tests the number against base 2 and then only tests random odd numbers, instead of completely random numbers. I figured this might get better probability than 1/4^k for k rounds since if we factor out all the powers of 2 from a random base there should be an odd remainder. Does this actually have better probability bounds, or would it be about the same, and how would we prove that? Also, even if it had the same probability bounds, would this test at least be faster in the average case scenario for random prime generation since the base 2 test weeds out almost all composites and the computer doesn't have to generate as many random numbers?

This is my code. I previously defined the functions MR(p, a, s, d) and extract(a, b) and a class PrimeList which uses trial division to generate a list of prime numbers; small_primes is the one instance I defined in the program.

```
def probable_prime(p, k = 5): #Quick custom-made primality test for large primes
    #Test small cases
    if p <= 5000:
        return small_primes.is_prime(p)

    #Find s, d
    (s, d) = extract(2, p - 1)

    #Test for divisibility by 2
    if s == 0:
        return False

    #Quick trial division for small primes
    for i in small_primes.odd_primes(p.bit_length() // 2):
        if p % i == 0:
            return False

    #Miller-Rabin test for base 2
    if not MR(p, 2, s, d):
        return False

    #Miller-Rabin test for odds only
    return all(MR(p, random.randint(2, p // 2) * 2 - 1, s, d) for i in range(k))
```

Comment: Even though you show code this question isn't really about programming but rather the underlying mathematics; it would be more ontopic at https://crypto.stackexchange.com instead. I think it would be ontopic at math.SX as well, but that doesn't focus on usage in crypto like crypto.SX does.

Comment: You have two hypotheses. You could test them both yourself to see that neither is true. A strong liar appears to be just as likely to be even as it is to be odd, and the same is true of a witness. Quoting from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), *...For testing arbitrarily large n, choosing bases at random is essential, as we don't know the distribution of witnesses and strong liars among the numbers 2, 3, …, n − 2...*

Comment: Why not simply run the die-harder test suite or something similar? Both NIST and BSI have a full range of tests that test the distribution of the generated random values. Using your own defined random tests seems to be a bit dangerous; you'll be testing those things that you've probably already thought of. The trick is to test it against tests that you may not have anticipated.